$| \ker{\phi} |<\infty \iff [G: \phi(G)]<\infty$ for group homomorphism $\phi$.
Let $G$ be a countably infinite abelian group.
If $\phi:G \to G$ is a group homomorphism is it true that either both $| \ker{\phi} |$ and $[G: \phi(G)]$ are finite or both infinite?
If so, is there some additional relation between $| \ker{\phi} |$ and $[G: \phi(G)]$?

Yes there is an additional relation - the first isomorphim theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_on_homomorphisms .

I am well aware of that. It only gives that $G / \ker{\phi} \cong \phi(G) $, which is NOT necessarily a relation between the cardinality of $\ker{\phi}$ and the index of $\phi(G)$ in $G$. Right? Does the first isomorphism theorem even imply a positive answer to my original question?

@Desperado That's not true. Consider $\mathbb{Z}$ and the map $n \mapsto 2n$. I think it only holds for finite groups, but I am not asking about these.

My mistake, I misread the question. Good question, and indeed the answer is no as the answer below explains.

In general, the answer is no.
Consider $G=\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$. It is known that $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z} = \bigoplus_p \Bbb{Z}_{p^\infty}$, where $\Bbb{Z}_{p^\infty}$ is the abelian group generated by elements $x_1,\dots,x_n,\dots$ such that $px_1=0$ and $px_{n+1}=x_n$. Consider the map $\Bbb{Z}_{p^\infty}\xrightarrow{\cdot p}\Bbb{Z}_{p^\infty}$. On generators, this maps $x_{n+1}\mapsto x_n$, thus is clearly surjective, and it has kernel generated by $x_1$, i.e. $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$.
Now let $\phi$ be the direct sum of these maps. It has kernel $\bigoplus_p \Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$, which is clearly infinite, and it is surjective, thus $[G:\phi(G)] = 1$, giving a counter-example.
As a sidenote: for finitely generated abelian groups the answer is yes. The proof basically boils down to the fact that a finitely generated group is infinite iff it has positive rank, and rank is dimension when tensoring with $\Bbb{Q}$, which preserves exactness, and then you can use rank-nullity for vector spaces.
